# Empty struct and anonymous union weird case

Tags: c++, struct, sizeof, unions

Compiling my code as C++11 with `gcc 4.8.2` and `llvm/clang 3.4` on fedora-linux, I got strange results that I couldn't really explain...
here is a similar program fedora.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

struct A {};
struct C {};
struct B1 : A { union { A a;}; };
struct B2 : A { union { C c;}; };

int main()
{
    cout << sizeof(B1) << " " << sizeof(B2) << endl;
}
```

`sizeof(B1) = 2` and `sizeof(B2) = 1`

But why are the sizes different? Actually I have an idea "why", but I want to find the exact explanation or C++ rule.

Comment: Actually `1, 1` for me under C++11.

Comment: @herohuyongtao Then it must be implementation specific, for I've got `2, 1` with g++4.8.

Comment: Could reproduce it with g++4.8.1 and std=c++11 on Linux/x86_64. Curious thing. Missed opportunity for empty-baseclass-optimisation?

Comment: @herohuyongtao: Any more about which platform/compiler?

Comment: @Deduplicator C++11 under MSVS13 (Windows).

Comment: fedora. tried with both gcc 4.8.2 and llvm/clang 3.4

Comment: windows/vs2012 - 1, 1

Comment: windows/vs2013 - 1, 1 as well

Comment: `2 1` for LinuxUbuntu14 on 64 bits with and without `-std=gnu++11` option and `1 1` on Win7 VSExpress2012. Is it `undefined behaviour`

Comment: why is that undefined behavior ?

Comment: ohhh, forgot to mention it's C++11

Comment: @thedarksideofthemoon You mean unspecified.

Answer (score 6):

The `B1` child has both a parent and sub-object of type `A`. Two distinct objects of the same type cannot exist at the same address, and the union separately contains an additional `A` to the parent `A`.

With `B2`, the empty base optimization allows the empty `A` parent and `C` member to share the single address of the child.

Comment: You may want to write out "empty base optimization" for clarity.

Comment: that was my assumption either. but what I can't get is what makes two objects "distinct" enough to produce such results?

Comment: Only since some time after C++11 standard.

Answer (score 2):

I think that there will be helpful two quotes from the C++ Standard. The first one defines what is subobject.

> 2 Objects can contain other objects, called subobjects. A subobject
>   can be a member subobject (9.2), a base class subobject (Clause 10),
>   or an array element.

The second one says that two subobjects of the same type may not have the same address

> A base class subobject may be of zero size (Clause 9); however, two
>   subobjects that have the same class type and that belong to the same
>   most derived object must not be allocated at the same address (5.10).
>   —end note ]

So in this class definition

```
struct B1 : A { union { A a;}; };
```

there are two subobjects of type A: base class subobject and member subobject a.

Also it is important to add that every member of every anonymous union is a member of the class containing the anonymous unions.

Comment: Is the fact that members of anonymous unions are also direct members of the containing struct/class/union really important here?

Comment: @Deduplicator In the last statement of my most starting with words "every member of every..." I cited the Standard.

Comment: Could you add which standard you quote? Because n3242, 1.8§6 would allow both interpretations: "Unless an object is a bit-field or a base class subobject of zero size, the address of that object is the address of the first byte it occupies. Two distinct objects that are neither bit-fields nor base class subobjects of zero
size shall have distinct addresses."

Comment: @Deduplicator I quoted Document Number: N3691 Date: 2013-05-16

Comment: Vlad, you got the wrong quotes to prove the point, because notices are non-normative (therefore bracketed), and the paragraph you took from 1.8 is not that relevant. The last paragraph would have been.

Comment: @Deduplicato What is the last paragraph?

Comment: @Deduplicato 1.8 only gives the definition of the notion of subobject.

Comment: Same as for the latest public draft in my answer.

Comment: @Deduplicator   This quote "...if at least one is a base class subobject of zero size and they are of different types; otherwise, they shall have distinct addresses" only confirms what I wrote.  So I do not see a problem.

Comment: I didn't say your conclusions are wrong, I just said you took the wrong quotes to support your point, and adding the standard version to the answer itself would make it even better.

Comment: @Deduplicator The quotes are not wrong. Simply the quoting could be more large.

Answer (score 1):

The C++11 standard can be interpreted to allow size 1 for both examples:

> #### 1.8 The C++ object model §6:
>
> Unless an object is a bit-field or a base class subobject of zero size, the address of that object is the address of the first byte it occupies. Two distinct objects that are neither bit-fields nor base class subobjects of zero size shall have distinct addresses.

There's at least one non-normative notice disallowing it for case 1, but it is non-normative:

> #### 10 Derived classes §8:
>
> [ Note: A base class subobject might have a layout (3.7) different from the layout of a most derived object of the same type. A base class subobject might have a polymorphic behavior (12.7) different from the polymorphic behavior of a most derived object of the same type. A base class subobject may be of zero size (Clause 9); however, two subobjects that have the same class type and that belong to the same most derived object must not be allocated at the same address (5.10). —end note ]

The latest publicly available draft (n3797 dated 2013-10-13) though disallows the first example to have size 1:

> #### 1.8 The C++ object model §6:
>
> Unless an object is a bit-field or a base class subobject of zero size, the address of that object is the address of the first byte it occupies. Two objects that are not bit-fields may have the same address if one is a subobject of the other, or if at least one is a base class subobject of zero size and they are of different types; otherwise, they shall have distinct addresses.

Answer (score 0):

thank you guys for quick response!!! I modified my code a bit with template trick so that actual object's data are the same but template types are different - works perfectly!!! for those who interested, now it looks something like this (T must not equal zero):

```
template<int T> struct A { enum{ val = T < 0 ? -T : T}; };
struct B1 : A<1> { union { A<-1> a;}; };
```

thank you